# Show other domain using DNS instead of iframe

Tags: redirect, dns

I got 2 domains bought at diferent providers and I would like http://aaaaa.com to show http://bbbbb.com/aaaaa

Is this possible using only DNS? must I transfer the domain to my hosting provider that has the http://bbbb.com domain? I really don't want to use a redirection or iframe.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that on DNS Level in two ways:

Depending on your Provider you can make http://DomainA.com/ redirect with masking to http://DomainB/Folder now this is premature way of doing it specially if SEO matters to you.

If you have your own servers or you can add Virtual Directory on the server you can point DomainA to this server and make http://DomainB/Folder location as start point.

This can be done with Apache, Nginx or IIS.

Please can you give me more explanations on what OS and what kind of hosting you have so i can help you with this? And also what kind of application because if your using .net its a bit different then using normal PHP or HTML or wordpress... U will need to add Virtual Directory to achieve this.

If your using shared hosting and have Apache web-server the easiest way to do it is so:
.htaccess and Apache also can handle such redirection. 
http://www.site5.com/blog/apache/htaccess/redirect-to-blog/20090427/

Regards and hope this helps.

Comment: I have shared apache hosting. Using the method in your link, should I just point the 2e domain using an a record to the IP of the first domain and will htaccess take care of the rest then?

Comment: If its shared with Apache point the two domains to the main folder, Make sure you can point both of them.

Then use .htaccess to manage the secondary domain to be sent to the folder for DomainB... if the link and .htaccess didnt work let me know i can write something for you.