# How to make url like username.example.com

Tags: laravel-5

I searched a lot about this topics. Maybe I wasn't in the right way or proper way. 
So my question is: how I can change url from `example.com/username` to  `username.example.com`?

Can I do this using Laravel?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, where is this an issue in your code?

Comment: I have build a site. Here, when a user loge in he get url like this example.com/hisname but I want to show him url like this hisname.example.com

Comment: Isn't this simple text substitution? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up a wildcard DNS entry first, so that your hostname works.

Comment: @Sahil Singh, Can you please say me details. I am just a beginner.

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, Where should I work to do this? In my laravel code or my cpanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to create a subdomain first - `username.example.com`.
Now to point `username.example.com` to  `example.com/username` you have two options -

1. configure virtual host (can be done at web server - [see this for apache server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts))

or

2. Some DNS servers give you an iframe. Basically this means that for any domain name (like `username.example.com`) they will give you an iframe, and you can configure the iframe to point to `example.com/username`. This configuration will have to be done at DNS server's portal.

Use only one of the above mentioned options, I would recommend option 1 over 
option 2.

Also see the following related question -
[Show other domain using DNS instead of iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513520/show-other-domain-using-dns-instead-of-iframe)